# Is there a way to track the rejected email from gmail delivery subsystem in C#?

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I have tried to use a nonexistence email to test.

```
...
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("nonexistenceemail@gmail.com"));
mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
SmtpClient client= new SmtpClient();
client.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
client.SendAsync(mail, "Send Async");
```

The callback is defined as follow:

```
private static void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   e.Cancelled || e.Error != null ? doSomething("fail") : doSomething("success");
}
```

Then when I check the mailbox, there is a rejected email from delivery subsystem of gmail.

```
 Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

 nonexistenceemail@gmail.com

 Technical details of permanent failure:
 Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for ...

 The error that the other server returned was:
 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
 550 5.1.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 cy1si14769573pdb.248 - gsmtp
```

However, the SendCompletedCallback tells that there is no cancel or error, it may not be designed to do callback in this way. In C# code, is there a way to identify such rejected email ?

Answer (score 0):

When your email gets rejected this happens after the mail is successfully sent. For example the mailbox could be full, nonexistant mail address and so on.
You'll have to fetch the bouncemails and check their headers in order to be able to supply your system with a reason why it failed.
Unfortunately most emailproviders do not send back those errors instantly so there's no foolproof way to do this "live", also not all providers obey RFC, specially small special company setups.

Maybe you can get inspiration for your solution out of the RFC for those cases

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5429